# When update ng-repeat item in list, only last one is updated

Tags: angularjs

I have ng-repeat list with some number. 
I also sum all number and show sum in footer of table.

Now I need, when manualy input number to SUM, calculate number in every item in ng-repat.

here, I in ng-repat call ng-init and pass $index and item to function for 
    calculate sum

```
<tr ng-repeat="item in myCartItems track by $index" ng- 
init="storeValueOnScope($index, item)">


$scope.storeValueOnScope = function(index, item){
  $rootScope.indexOdabranihKlupa = index;
  $rootScope.impresijeKampanja = item.campaignImpressions;
}
```

the difference in percentage between the maximum number of impressions and 
    the number of impressions selected

```
$scope.getUserSelectedImpresion = function (impressions){
   $scope.userSelectedImpressionsSumBench = impressions;

   $scope.percentageDiff = $scope.userSelectedImpressionsSumBench  / 
     $rootScope.totaImpressionsSum * 100;

   $scope.calculateDiff($rootScope.indexOdabranihKlupa, 
     $rootScope.impresijeKampanja);
}
```

here I calculate the new number and I want to put a new number in ng-repeat already loaded in DOM

```
$scope.calculateDiff = function(index, item) {
  $scope.myCartItems[index].campaignImpressions = (item * 
    $scope.percentageDiff) / 100; 
}
```

here is the part where I want to get the new value

```
<input type="number" ng-model="item.campaignImpressions" ng-min="0" ng- 
max="item.maxValue" class="inputPolje" name="campaignImpressions" />
```

**Problem**

when I calculate all of this, I get correct number, but only for last item, not for every in ng-repeat list

```
 |ID   | Available impressions (input) |
 |1000 |       5000                    | max: 5000
 |1004 |       5000                    | max: 5000
 |1098 |       4666.666666666666       | max: 5000 //only this one is calculated
 total max: 15000 (input field)
 user select: 14000 //this is number for make calculation
```

here is my json example

```
[{
"id": 1000,
"campaignImpressions": 5000,
"mediaImpressions": 5000,
"time": "20:30:00"
 }, {
"id": 1004,
"campaignImpressions": 5000,
"mediaImpressions": 5000,
"time": "20:30:00"
 }, {
"id": 1004,
"campaignImpressions": 5000,
"mediaImpressions": 5000,
"time": "20:30:00"
 }]
```

Comment: You forgot to show us your `ng-repeat` statement. Where is the markup? It would also help to give us a sample of the data

Comment: Oh sry... i forget add ng-repeat.

Comment: I don't have json now, becouse im leave office... but it's very simple... they have itemId and campaignImpressions. CampaignImpressions is also max value.

Comment: @Pop-A-Stash i update my question